# Does the ReDim statement initialise String Arrays with empty strings?

Tags: arrays, vba, vb6

Given the following statements in VBA:
Assume that `val =  4` and `Option Base 0`

```
Dim dataStr() As String
ReDim dataStr(val)
```

Will the ReDim statement initialise the String array dataStr to 5 empty string elements(0 to 4).
What exactly will be the contents of the Array after the execution of the ReDim statement.

Comment: You can skip the Dim, just use `ReDim dataStr(val) As String`. Works with `Option Explicit`. Intellisense freaks a bit though.

Comment: You **can** skip the Dim, but the VB6 manual warns against it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub RedimStringArray()

Dim Val As Integer
Dim dataStr() As String
Dim idx As Long

    Val = 4

    ReDim dataStr(Val)

    For idx = LBound(dataStr) To UBound(dataStr)
        Debug.Print idx, """" & dataStr(idx); """", TypeName(dataStr(idx)), Len(dataStr(idx))
    Next

End Sub
```

gives me this:

```
 0            ""            String         0 
 1            ""            String         0 
 2            ""            String         0 
 3            ""            String         0 
 4            ""            String         0
```

So I'd say that yes, ReDim re-initializes the array with empty strings.

Comment: Why did you "Dim idx As Long", why not "Dim idx As Integer"

Comment: At least in Excel on Win32, Long is the "native" VBA integer type; Integer just gets converted to Long. So, it's common to see integral variables declared as Long by default. Declaring a variable as Integer means you actually want VBA to treat it like one, raising an overflow error if you assign it 32768, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could just read the [VB6 manual page on ReDim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231(VS.60).aspx)?

> When variables are initialized, a
>   variable-length string is initialized
>   to a zero-length string (""), and a
>   fixed-length string is filled with
>   zeros

Comment: "a fixed-length string is filled with zeros" sounds odd. I guess by "zero" they mean Chr$(0).

Comment: ...good point about fixed-length strings arrays not being initalized as zero-lenth strings, though.

Comment: Yes, it's Chr$(0). It sounds to me like the VB6 runtime fills the whole block of memory for the array with zeros. So numbers go to zero, pointers go to null, but fixed-length strings go to Chr$(0).

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm the answer from Mike Woodhouse, see section 5.4.3.3 of the VBA Language Specification:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851%28PROT.10%29.aspx

> Each array in a <redim-statement>
>   is resized according to the dimensions
>   specified in its <bounds-list>.
>   Each element in the array is reset to
>   the default value for its data type,
>   unless the word “preserve” is
>   specified.